# Asp.net:FullCalendar does not load events

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

Hello i was following several tutorials on to implement fullcalendar on my asp.net application but when i launch my application the calendar doesn't load the events  . 
here's my index.chtml :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div id="calender"></div>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="pDetails"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />



@section scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/conge/getConges",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            title: v.Subject,
                            description: v.Description,
                            start: moment(v.DateDebut),
                            end: v.DateFin != null ? moment(v.DateFin) : null,
                            color: v.themecolor,
                            allDay: v.IsFullDay
                        });
                    })

                    GenerateCalender(events);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            })

            function GenerateCalender(events) {
                $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                    contentHeight: 400,
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                    },
                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventColor: '#378006',
                    events: events,
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                        var $description = $('<div/>');
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        if (calEvent.end != null) {
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        }
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                        $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                        $('#myModal').modal();
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    </script>
}
```

and the function i'm using to display it :

```
  public JsonResult getConges()
        {
            using (dbContext dbmodel = new dbContext())
            {
                var events = dbmodel.conges.ToList();
                return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }

        }
```

I didn't get any errors so i don't know how to solve it . i'm using mysql database .

so please if you're familiar with this error help me.

[Updated]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines

```
DateDebut: moment(v.DateDebut),
DateFin: v.DateFin != null ? moment(v.DateFin) : null
```

are the problem.

fullCalendar doesn't recognise the `DateDebut` and `DateFin` properties - it only recognises `start` and `end` as valid property names for the dates. Instead write

```
start: v.DateDebut,
end: v.DateFin != null ? v.DateFin : null
```

You have a similar problem in your calendar setup code, where

```
conges: conges
```

needs to be

```
events: conges
```

Those two changes ought to fix your problem. N.B. I have removed the moment() constructors - assuming your date strings are in a valid format that momentJS can recognise without being given a custom format, then fullCalendar will recognise it too, without needing to wrap it in a moment object first.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object for a list of the required and optional property names recognised by fullCalendar for an event.

Comment: Thank you for responding in fact  i changed itto start and end it’s the same no data loaded

Comment: Ok. Can you please edit the question to show a sample of the JSON data being returned? There's a chance it's an issue with date formats or something like that. Also check your browser's console for any errors.

Comment: Oh actually I just noticed another problem: `conges: conges` should be `events: conges` in your calendar code. Again, fullCalendar only recognises the "events" property name in the options. Have updated the answer.

Comment: oh thanks when i changed it to events worked . i will update it . thank you again

Comment: No problem. In future remember to double-check the fullCalendar documentation that a) you've used names which are actually mentioned in the documentation and b) you haven't forgotten to translate any words :-)

Comment: i will the next time :)